# awakeAfterUsingCoder() causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, exception

I've got a UIView designed in InterfaceBuilder that has a Swift backing class. I'm using `awakeAfterUsingCoder()` to substitute the instantiated nib like so:

```
public override func awakeAfterUsingCoder(aDecoder: NSCoder) -> AnyObject? {
    if self.subviews.count == 1 && self.subviews[0].isKindOfClass(UILabel) {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: bundle).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)
        return nib[0] as! CustomView
    }

    return self
}
```

However, now I keep getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crashes in the AppDelegate. I turned on zombies and was able to get this message:

> *** -[ModuleName.CustomView _referenceView]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xed13600

`_referenceView` must be defined somewhere in the framework, though I didn't see it when I navigated `self` stopped at a breakpoint. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view in my storyboard was defined as a `UIButton` (since my CustomView is a UIButton subclass). I replaced it with a generic empty `UIView`, I replaced the condition with:

```
if self.subviews.isEmpty {
```

and everything worked right.